# PHP Mail Form - Checkbox Array

Tags: php, html, forms, email, checkbox

So I've looked around at several older questions here on Stack Overflow and none of them seem to give me the right output so I figured I should just ask my own question.

This is likely a very basic answer, I am just not well versed in PHP. I am trying to send an array of checkboxes via e-mail to no success so far. Below is a small sample from what I have so far in the form:

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="colorstones[White]" value="White" />White
<input type="checkbox" name="colorstones[Pink]" value="Pink" />Pink
<input type="checkbox" name="colorstones[Yellow]" value="Yellow" />Yellow
<input type="checkbox" name="colorstones[Light Brown/Cognac]" value="Light Brown/Cognac" />Light Brown/Cognac
```

**PHP**

```
$finish_colors = implode(', ', $_POST['colorstones']);
$body = $colorstones;

$subject = 'Scio Test Form Submission';
$headers = 'From: example@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: example@example.com';
$to = 'example@example.com';

mail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

The e-mail sends fine, and all of the other text/radio fields that I have send fine, it just seems to be the checkboxes that give me an issue. The output of this when assigning $colorstones to $body, returns nothing in the message body.

Joey

Answer (score 3):

```
$colorstones = implode(', ', $_POST['colorstones']);
$body = $colorstones;

$subject = 'Scio Test Form Submission';
$headers = 'From: example@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: example@example.com';
$to = 'example@example.com';

mail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

Comment: Oh wow..used the wrong variable (palm to face). Thanks for pointing out my silly mistake Qaisar, too early in the morning I suppose!